# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException during gradle build

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I'm working on a java project with spring boot, and building it with gradle. I was successfully able to run 'gradle build'. But after than when I run `'java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar'`, it throws me `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error`. It searches for mainClassName attribute in the build.gradle file. I tries setting it up, still it gives me the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Few more details:

1. my package name: com.foo.bar
2. file that contains main method: FileData.java
3. I am adding 'mainClassName = 'com.foo.bar.FileData' in my build.gradle file.
4. Error it throws:

   ```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foo.bar.FileData
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
       at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:177)
       at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:143)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
       at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
   ```

Thanks for your help

Comment: share your gradle build file please

Comment: Then you rin java -jar it has nothing common with gradle. You have to provide main class property in your manifest file. So, just take a look imto your jar and check whether a class exists and provide your build.gradle please.

Comment: It seems your class does not end up in the built jar. Make sure the class file is on the source directory and try cleaning and rebuilding. Also make sure your main method has the correct header.